# text to object actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm creating a keyboard for my logographic writing script and I'm trying to implement a back button.  The program records the last object coloured in the textfield LastType.  I'm trying to use the content of LastType as the name of the object I want to colour white (thus hiding it from sight).  However I can't get it to recognise Test as the name of a property/object. How can I do this?

```
Back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, BackClick);

function BackClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    var variable = textField1.text;
    var es:Number = variable;
    es = 0xFFFFFF;
    var Test:Object = LastType[text]
    var colorTransform:ColorTransform = Test.transform.colorTransform;
    colorTransform.color = es;
    Test.transform.colorTransform = colorTransform;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

---

This solution from Organis worked;

```
var Test:DisplayObject = getChildByName(LastType.text);
```

Many Thanks!  :-)

Comment: If you want to get an object whose instance name is identical to what is in the **LastType** (which is presumably a **TextField**), you need to **var Test:DisplayObject = getChildByName(LastType.text);** Furthermore, to hide something you can simply set **Test.visible = false;** rather than coloring it white.

Comment: That works!  Thank you!  <3  Brilliant!